# Converting DVI to HDMI

Tags: hdmi, dvi

I have a graphics card with a VGA and DVI-I Dual-Link ports but my monitor/screen only supports HDMI. I've searched over the Web about pictures  and I got a lot of images of DVI to HDMI adapters but I am not sure how reliable they are or if it will work.

There are shops in my location that sell DVI-D to HDMI cables/adapter and I doubt that it will work since they don't offer testing. You need to buy them before testing.

I am planning to upgrade my graphics card so I don't want to buy
expensive converters.

Comment: Adapters will work. Here in Poland you can buy them for equivalent of $3. It's not that much, especially compared to graphics card upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been using converters and combined cables (all of the above) back and forth (for computer monitors and for televisions) -- they work very effectively. The real difference is that the HDMI cables can include audio, but DVI cannot so connecting the two will filter out audio to the DVI end.

One piece of advice however, don't get extremely long HDMI cables as the signal only goes so far and you will need to also purchase a signal booster if you do.

Comment: Another question. My graphic card has a DVI-I female port. Will DVI-D male port will work into it? DVI-D male will surely fit on DVI-I since it only lacks 4 pins.

Comment: It does work. The reverse of course would not match up (pins and no ports) but of course that you do know.

Comment: DVI-I just means it supports both the VGA and DVI-D outputs (it has analogue as well as digital outputs). DVI-D just means you're missing VGA, which frankly no one should need these days :D

Comment: I do have a dvi-hdmi cable as mentioned and I like it a lot, feels better than a bunch of cables and adapters strung together. but i do have those too (same av setup for different reasons)

Comment: Additionally as mentioned in a different answer I got a converter here to combine DVI and Audio to HDMI for my TV if you ever choose to include audio: http://www.monoprice.com/Search/Index?keyword=dvi+audio+to+hdmi

Comment: Can someone confirm that this also works for dual link and resolutions up to `2,560 × 1,600`. I have been reading about different adapters from DVI-D (on the grafic card) to HDMI (on the monitor), and I saw reports that only full HD is supported with adapters.

Comment: My settings are Dual-Link with resolutions up to 2560x1600 on my (old) 2011 laptop that I bought it for -- specs on my laptop are here: https://support.apple.com/kb/sp619?locale=en_US

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure DVI doesn't support audio, so if you're trying to get audio across you might be out of luck, but otherwise HDMI can be thought of as a superset of DVI in many ways, and is designed to support interoperability with DVI.

In summary, yes, a DVI->HDMI cable should work just fine. I've used them in the past for my PC and they've worked just fine.

Comment: More specifically, the signalling in DVI is also supported by HDMI, so it doesn't need an expensive converter.

Comment: I'll just use the display and I have a separate audio port so I don't mind if it doesn't have sound

Comment: Same here, I have an DVI out on my computer lead to an HDMI in on my television at the house. Quite effective. (Everything I mentioned in my answer is in use literally as I am writing this.)

Comment: For mine, since I have a TV as the end point I wanted audio, I got it combined with with a converter (about 40 bucks but it works): http://www.monoprice.com/Search/Index?keyword=dvi+audio+to+hdmi